# Meaning of "Setting the alarm clock aside"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have some troubles with understanding the first part of below sentence.
When the girl wake up late because of broken clock she said this

> Setting the alarm clock **aside**, why did they have to cut the power today, of all day?

I have no idea the purpose of word "aside" here

Comment: Some more context might be helpful, but it sounds to me that she's emphasising that, although the loss of power has caused her to oversleep, it's also caused her a separate and much larger problem. In other words, she's setting the issue of the alarm clock *aside* to focus on whatever this other problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "set something aside" is to put it move it out of the way. Like you might say, "There were so many tools on the work bench that I set all the screwdrivers and drill bits aside so that I had room to work." The phrase can also be used non-literally, to refer to put off considering some issue or idea. Like, "Setting aside the question of how much it costs, let us first consider whether it is effective."

I can see that there might be some confusion here for someone learning English, because we say "setting an alarm clock" to mean, "adjusting the alarm clock to control the time that it will ring". That has nothing to do with the present sentence. "Setting an alarm clock" and "setting an alarm clock aside" have most of the same words, but they mean totally different, unrelated things.

You could say "I am going to set the alarm clock aside" to mean that you are going to pick it up and put it some place where it is not in the way. But that doesn't look like what the writer meant here. He follows "set the alarm clock aside" with a statement indicating that cutting the power caused many problems. So here he means not physically moving the alarm clock somewhere, but rather, disregarding the issue of the alarm clock -- which I would guess presumably means that the clock did not ring and thus failed to wake her up -- because the loss of power has caused other, more important problems.